# Tensorflow 2.5.0 and Gensim 4.0.1 compatibility with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow2.0, gensim

I have a compatibility issue when running :
`pip install numpy==1.19.4`
`pip install tensorflow=2.5.0`
`pip install gensim==4.0.1`

On Ubuntu 18.04, with Python 3.9.5 (installs made inside docker container).

I get the following exception when trying to import gensim:
`ValueError: numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject.` 
Not sure how i can make this work, I tried downgrading several libraries but still not achieved to make it work in Ubuntu.

Edit : it works on Python 3.8.10

Answer (score 1):

It is the numpy version , downgrade numpy to 1.19.2 or lower and see.

Comment: Tensorflow can't run with numpy 1.20 (must be 1.19.2). But gensim can't run with numpy 1.19 (must using numpy 1.20).

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow is currently not compatible with numpy 1.20.
Also, many changes happened from gensim 3.X to 4.X, which may lead to some problems.

Try installing the following setup:

- numpy 1.19.2
- gensim 3.8.3
- tensorflow 2.3.0